# How would you write this in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I never really learned VB.NET, how would you write this in VB.NET?

Here is the code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd_tracking_file.FileName);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
```

Would it be like this?

```vb
Dim file As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(ofd_tracking_file.FileName)

While Not line = file.ReadLine() = Nothing    
End While
```

And no, converters do not work, I already tried.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it compile? Did it run correctly? Also, the code seems to convert fine in here http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I do not know what InlineAssignHelper is?

Comment: I found my answer here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/inlineassignhelper

Comment: I would use parenthesis for `(line = file.ReadLine())`, for clarity at least. Why not just use `<> Nothing` instead of that `Not`?

Comment: Rather than embedding the solution in your question, post it below as an **answer**.  That way you may get upvotes

Comment: Honestly that `InlineAssignHelper` smells of _bad practice_ to me

Comment: @MickyD : It is. The best practice in my opinion is to check `StreamReader.EndOfStream`.

Comment: InlineAssignHelper is overkill for this simple case.

Comment: @Andrew - `<>` doesn't work with `Nothing`.  That's why VB has the `Is` and `IsNot` operators.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, yes, I saw that later. So then: why not just use `IsNot  Nothing` instead? :)

Answer (score 1):

The C# code uses an assignment within expression - these are not available in VB.
The VB equivalent is:

```vb
Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(ofd_tracking_file.FileName)
line = file.ReadLine()
Do While line IsNot Nothing
    ...
    line = file.ReadLine()
Loop
```

You can avoid the extra 'ReadLine' statement, if you can stomach an unconditional loop with an 'Exit Do' - just stating options:

```vb
Do
    line = file.ReadLine()
    If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    ...
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick using the classic pattern of:

```vb
Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(ofd_tracking_file.FileName)

Dim line = file.ReadLine()
While line IsNot Nothing
    'blah blah
    line = file.ReadLine()
End While
```

The benefit of this approach is that only a single guard statement is required, though you are required to have two `ReadLine` statements.

Personally, the `InlineAssignHelper` suggested by Telerik is a bad pattern which just makes your code unclear.

Comment: @sstan Thanks for edit, I couldn't work out why it wasn't recognising the language right :)

Comment: It's because the C# tag is ahead of the VB.NET tag in this particular question.  When that happens, you need to explicitly set the language for the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If you concerns about your code readability then using pure `vb.net` code will be better choice in your case.

```vb
Using reader As New StreamReader(ofd_tracking_file.FileName)
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    Do
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        Debug.Write(line)
    Loop Until line Is Nothing
End Using
```

or using `EndOfStream` property will be more readable on my opinion (thanks to @Visual Vincent)

```vb
Using reader As New StreamReader(ofd_tracking_file.FileName)
    While reader.EndOfStream = false
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        'use line value
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: Your first example won't work - when the line eventually becomes 'Nothing' you are using it before the 'loop until' condition is checked, so you will get a null reference exception.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, it will work if using of line can handle `null` value. But you are right that first example will need extra checking. I added first example because the part `Loop Until line Is Nothing` is very good example of readability :)